# OPA matcher for sap.m.MessageToast.show call?

Tags: regression-testing, sapui5

How does a OPA match pattern for a `sap.m.MessageToast.show` call looks like?
I looked into the Code of `sap.m.MessageToast.show` and assumed the use control is `sap.ui.core.Popup`. Therefore I tried the following matcher:

```
iShouldSeeAToastMessage : function() {
    return this.waitFor({
        controlType : "sap.ui.core.Popup",
        success : function (aDialog) {              
            ok(true, "Found a Toast: " + aDialog[0]);
        },
        errorMessage : "No Toast message detected!"
    });
},
```

Is the controlType correct? How could the matcher section look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
return this.waitFor({
    pollingInterval : 100,
    viewName : "YOUR_VIEW_NAME_HERE",
    check : function () {
        return !!sap.ui.test.Opa5.getJQuery()(".sapMMessageToast").length;
    },
    success : function () {
        ok(true, "Found a Toast");
    },
    errorMessage : "No Toast message detected!"
});
```

Comment: is pollingInterval the same as clock.tick?