# OPA matcher for sap.m.MessageToast with expected content

Tags: sapui5

I have a similar question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425828/opa-matcher-for-sap-m-messagetoast-show-call)

But, how can I check the content of `sap.m.MessageToast` is correct or not?

```
iShouldSeeAToastMessage : function(sText) {
    return this.waitFor({
        pollingInterval : 100,
        check : function() {
            return !!sap.ui.test.Opa5.getJQuery()(".sapMMessageToast").length;
        },
        success : function (oMessage) {
            strictEqual(oMessage[0].getText(), sText, "The message display correctly");
        },
        errorMessage : "No Toast message detected!"
    });
}
```

I tried the above code. But, maybe, the `success` callback returns no object. So, I got the error message: *Cannot read property '0' of null*

=======================================

I tried the following code. The testcase is passed. But, I am not sure it is a correct test code.

```
success : function () {
    strictEqual(sap.ui.test.Opa5.getJQuery()(".sapMMessageToast")[0].innerHTML, sText, "The message display correctly");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I built a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yunapiguze/1/edit?html,output) illustrating a matcher.

Here is the matcher code:

```
new Opa5().waitFor({
            matchers: function () {
              return  jQuery(".sapMMessageToast").text();
            },
            success: function (sMessage) {
              MessageToast.show("found a message toast with the message " + sMessage);
            }
});
```

If you return something differen than a boolean in matchers it will get passed to success.

it is described in [the API documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.test.Opa5.html#waitFor) in the 'matchers' parameter.